# Reducing space in graph of tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-styles, tikz-cd, size

I have the following graph on Tikz.

```
\begin{tikzcd}


                                      &                                          &                                        &                                                     & \overline{\varnothing}                                          &                                          &                             &                                          &                             \\
                                       & \overline{B} \arrow[rrru]                &                                        &                                                     &                                                                 &                                          &                             & \overline{N} \arrow[lllu]                &                             \\
                                       &                                          &                                        &                                                     & C \arrow[rrru] \arrow[lllu]                                     &                                          &                             &                                          &                             \\
                                       &                                          &                                        & \overline{S} \arrow[ruuu]                           &                                                                 & T \arrow[luuu]                           &                             &                                          &                             \\
\overline{R} \arrow[ruuu] \arrow[rrru] &                                          & \overline{F} \arrow[rrru] \arrow[luuu] &                                                     &                                                                 &                                          & F \arrow[lllu] \arrow[ruuu] &                                          & R \arrow[lllu] \arrow[luuu] \\
                                       &                                          &                                        & \overline{T} \arrow[ruuu] \arrow[lllu] \arrow[rrru] &                                                                 & S \arrow[rrru] \arrow[lllu] \arrow[luuu] &                             &                                          &                             \\
                                       &                                          &                                        &                                                     & \overline{C} \arrow[ruuu] \arrow[luuu]                          &                                          &                             &                                          &                             \\
                                       & N \arrow[luuu] \arrow[ruuu] \arrow[rrru] &                                        &                                                     &                                                                 &                                          &                             & B \arrow[ruuu] \arrow[lllu] \arrow[luuu] &                             \\
                                       &                                          &                                        &                                                     & \varnothing \arrow[lllu] \arrow[luuu] \arrow[ruuu] \arrow[rrru] &                                          &                             &                                          &                            
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

I would like to know if there is any way to reduce it so that it is more similar to the following image:
[image]

I don't want to change the visuals, just make it look more compact in the document.
I made this graph with the help of https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/

Comment: `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]`. You can set `column sep` and `row sep` to any length, e.g., `column sep=3mm,row sep=3mm`

Comment: Thank you very much, they turned up perfectly.
I think I don't have the level to rate your answer for now, but I will rate it for future viewing.